# If returning string via assembly requires pointer, length and data in memory, why there is no pointer in memory when returning using return keyword?

Tags: solidity, remix, evm

1- Solidity:

```
function name() external view returns(string memory) { 
 return _name;                       // No pointer slot
}
```

2- Assembly:

```
function name() external view returns(string memory) {

 uint256 len = bytes(_name).length;

 assembly {
   let mp := mload(0x40)
   mstore(mp, 0x20)                  // Pointer
   mstore(add(mp, 0x20), len)        // Length

   switch lt(len, 32)         
   case 1 {
     mstore(add(mp, 0x40), sload(3)) // Data
   }
   default {
     // Ignore for now
   }

   return(mp, 0x60)                  // 3 Words
 }

}
```

When I debugged memory on Remix, the first one had no pointer slot but only length and data. The second one had pointer, length and data slot.

My questions are:

1. Why the solidity return has no pointer slot for the string in memory.
2. Why remix is unable to decode if I remove the pointer slot from
   second one.
3. What is the significance of pointer slot in this case ? When to use, when not to use ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return data should be ABI-encoded, same way as arguments, but excluding 4-byte selector. Solidity compiler handles ABI-encoding on its own - in assembly it’s your responsibility.

By the way revert usually contains ABI encoded result with selector of `Error(string)` or custom Solidity error selector.

ABI encoded parameters of variable length as strings and dynamic arrays are always presented as relative offsets to data containing length prefix.

Comment: Does that mean, solidity compiler keeps the pointer outside of EVM memory allocation when using solidity's return ?

Comment: @Xirexor nope, I would say solidity compiler allocates new memory for abi encoding and copy memory string with offset and length

Comment: Is the offset relative incase of calldata arguments too ?